# Creating a Drupal user with user_save doesn't automatically join an existing CiviCRM contact record

Tags: 7, civicrm, users

I have a custom module that will create a Drupal user programmatically using `user_save` as follows:

```
  //set up the user fields
  $fields = array(
    'mail' => $email,
    'pass' => $password,
    'name' => $username,
    'status' => 1,
    'init' => $email,
    'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
    'roles' => array(2 => 'authenticated user'),
  );

  //the first parameter is left blank so a new user is created
  $account = user_save('', $fields);
```

I have first done a check using the CiviCRM API to make sure that if an existing contact is already in the database and has a Drupal account associated with it, we don't create a new one. Also I check to make sure the email address isn't registered from the Drupal side.

The problem is, when I create a new user, it is not linking up to an existing CiviCRM contact record that uses the same email address and I'm ending up with a duplicate contact record.

How can I force the site to link to an existing record if the email address is a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to synchronize Drupal users and CiviCRM contacts is [`CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch::synchronize()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Core/BAO/UFMatch.php#L62).

Since you're calling [`user_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7), CiviCRM's `hook_user_insert` implementation should get triggered (from `user_module_invoke('insert', $edit, $account, $category);` in `user_save()`.

CiviCRM's [`civicrm_user_insert()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/blob/7.x-master/civicrm_user.inc#L60) checks whether it thinks you are on a CiviCRM callback already[*](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/blob/acd8dbc44983be1f3a18f14b58c17034da2589be/civicrm.module#L495), then calls either [`civicrm_register_data()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/blob/acd8dbc44983be1f3a18f14b58c17034da2589be/civicrm.module#L536) which will in turn call `CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch::synchronize()`, or `CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch::synchronize()` directly.

To deal with this you could trace your way through CiviCRM's code (drupal/civicrm.module, drupal/civicrm_user.inc, CRM/Core/BAO/UFMatch.php) and work out which path your code is triggering; ultimately you want to end up with a call to `CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch::synchronize()` which passes in the parameters for CiviCRM to correctly match the existing and new data.

You *could* also just call that function directly from your custom code; that might be less robust as in future you might end up triggering the synchronize call twice ...

Comment: If after investigating you believe CiviCRM isn't behaving correctly here, please consider taking the time to create an account and document your issue on [the CiviCRM issue tracker](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira).

Comment: Consider committing to the [CiviCRM Stackexchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm) to help grow a better forum for such questions in future!

Comment: Thanks for such an in depth answer, I will work from this. Sorry for the delay in response. And yes, we are getting close on the CiviCRM Stackexchange site!